# Webpack environment.plugins.prepend SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: webpack

In my environment.js file I have the following:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  }),
)
```

And  I am getting a syntax error on the last closing `)`:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

I need to load jquery into webpack, and I can't figure out why it is throwing the syntax error when other's seem to be using `plugins.prepend`.

My backend is Rails 5.1 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to remove the comma before the last closing `)`

```
environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  })
)
```